# When reading text file, I have an error about sharing violation in Unity3D

Tags: c#, parsing, unity-game-engine, lua, stream

I have some errors about IOException: Sharing violation.
My simulation program creates text file per 1/60s.
This code is written by Lua script.

This is Lua code. data.txt file is rewrite per 1/60s.
So, The content in file is changed per 1/60s.

```
  function dataListener:post( t )
    --local fn = "data"
    local fn = "time"
    --local filename = fn.."_"..60*t..".txt"
    local filename = fn..".txt"
    local file = io.open(filename, "w+")


    --file:write(string.format("%d; %d; %d\n",x,y,z))
    --file:write("%d; %d; %d\n", xx, yy, zz)
    --file:write(xx/100," ", yy/100," ", zz/100," ", wxx/100," ", wyy/100," ", wzz/100," \n")
    file:write(60*t," \n")
    file:close()
  end
```

And Unity3D read this file in Update() function.

This is Unity3D C# code.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;
using System.IO;

public class Textparsing : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GUISkin skin;
    private int currentTextNumber;// text number


    string s;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        currentTextNumber = 0;
        s = LoadTextFile("text/time.txt");
        print(s);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        s = LoadTextFile("text/time.txt");
        print(s);
    }
    string LoadTextFile(string fileName)
    {
        string t = "";
        string line = "";
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Application.dataPath + "/Resources/" + fileName);
        if (sr == null)
        {
            print("Error : " + Application.dataPath + "/Resources/" + fileName);
        }
        else
        {
            line = sr.ReadLine();
            while (line != null)
            {
                t += line;
                line = sr.ReadLine();
                if (line != null)
                {
                    t += "\n";
                }
            }
            sr.Close();
            // print("Loaded " + Application.dataPath + "/Resources/db/" + fileName);
        }
        return t;
    }

    //gui
    void OnGUI()
    {
        //read
        GUI.skin = skin;

        int halfW = Screen.width / 2;
        int halfH = Screen.height / 2;

        int x = 40;
        int y = halfH + 40;

        GUI.Label(new Rect(x, y, halfW * 1, halfH * 1.2f), s);
    }
}
```

In unity3D, This error occurs.

Error

```
IOException: Sharing violation on path C:\Users\Public\Documents\Unity Projects\textparsing\Assets\Resources\text\time.txt
System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean anonymous, FileOptions options) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/FileStream.cs:320)
System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
(wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileStream:.ctor (string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare)
System.IO.File.OpenRead (System.String path) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/File.cs:363)
System.IO.StreamReader..ctor (System.String path, System.Text.Encoding encoding, Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, Int32 bufferSize) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/StreamReader.cs:167)
System.IO.StreamReader..ctor (System.String path)
(wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.StreamReader:.ctor (string)
Textparsing.LoadTextFile (System.String fileName) (at Assets/Textparsing.cs:36)
Textparsing.Update () (at Assets/Textparsing.cs:29)
```

It is possible to read this file? or Is there any alternative method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most likely are trying to read the text file while it is being written to from your other program. This is not possible, you need to wait until one program is done writing, closes the file and then Unity can open and read it.

Also, writing and reading a file in Update is a bad idea. Those are far too many disk operations, which will be incredibly slow and also makes synchronization impossible, as you already experienced.

For a solution: What's the purpose of those two programs communicating? And why so fast? If you only have updates every once in a while you could use the [FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) class to monitor the text file and every time it changes, the changed event of the watcher will be called. But there are probably many other better solutions to your problem. Maybe SQL databases, or making it a plugin for Unity, socket communication, whatever the use case is, it depends.